# How to create a summary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have rows:

```
PLACE   DATE_OPEN   SUM
-----------------------
PLACE1  03.09.2018  2
PLACE2  03.09.2018  2
PLACE1  04.09.2018  8
PLACE1  05.09.2018  9
PLACE2  05.09.2018  1
```

I get the rows using this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    SB AS [PLACE], 
    CAST(OPEN_TIME AS DATE) AS [DATE_OPEN], 
    COUNT(ID) AS [SUM]
FROM
    [Table]
WHERE
    SB IN ('PLACE1', 'PLACE2')
GROUP BY 
    SB, CAST(OPEN_TIME AS DATE)
```

I want to get a table in the form of a summary table, is it possible to do this using SQL?

Example of the desired output:

```
PLACE   DATE_OPEN   
        03.09.2018  04.09.2018  05.09.2018
PLACE1  2           8           9
PLACE2  2                       1
```

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server dynamic SQL".

Comment: this seems like report data. Use a matrix in SSRS. But I would recommend switching rows and columns so you have a known width and unlimited rows.

Comment: You should **not** call a column `SUM` - especially if it contains a **count** ...... first of all, `SUM` is a reserved T-SQL keyword and it's always a bad idea to "re-use" these very generic names - use something **more expressive**, more useful in your case. And calling a column that contains a **count** `SUM` violates the *Principle Of Least Surprise* - either it's a sum, or it's a count - but don't mix those meanings - that'll make your code just that much harder and trickier to understand and maintain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest is PIVOT:

```
WITH Demo AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('PLACE1', '03.09.2018', 2),
    ('PLACE2', '03.09.2018', 2),
    ('PLACE1', '04.09.2018', 8),
    ('PLACE1', '05.09.2018', 9),
    ('PLACE2', '05.09.2018', 1)) T(PLACE, DATE_OPEN, [SUM])
)
SELECT * FROM Demo
PIVOT (SUM([Sum]) FOR Date_Open IN ([03.09.2018],[04.09.2018],[05.09.2018])) P
```

**Result**

```
PLACE  03.09.2018  04.09.2018  05.09.2018
------ ----------- ----------- -----------
PLACE1 2           8           9
PLACE2 2           NULL        1
```